# How to make the "sanitize" Rails method to leave a space where an HTML used to be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I'm doing the following:

```
sanitize(self.content, :tags => %w(""))
```

So I'm taking something like this:

`<p>one two three four five six seven eight nine then eleven</p><p>twelve thirteen</p>`

And turning it into something like this:

`one two three four five six seven eight nine then eleventwelve thirteen`

As you can see there is a problem here: `eleventwelve`

How can I do it so there is a space left between `eleven` and `twelve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom sanitizer :) [updated]

```
# models/custom_sanitizer.rb

class CustomSanitizer  
  def do(html, *conditions)
    document = HTML::Document.new(html)    
    export = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new # or just String
    parse(document.root) do |node|
      if node.is_a?(HTML::Text)
        if node.parent.is_a?(HTML::Tag) && match(node.parent, conditions) && export.present?
          export << " "
        end
        export << node.to_s
      end
    end
    export
  end

  private

  def match(node, conditions = [])
    eval(conditions.map {|c| "node.match(#{c})"}.join(" || "))
  end

  def parse(node, &block)
    node.children.each do |node|
      yield node if block_given?
      if node.is_a?(HTML::Tag)
        parse(node, &block)
      end
    end
  end

end

# Helper

def custom_sanitize(*args)
  CustomSanitizer.new.do(*args)
end
```

Basic usage:

```
custom_sanitize(html, conditions)
# where conditions is a hash or hashes like {:tag => "p", :attributes => {:class => "new_line"}}
```

Your example:

```
html = "<p>one two three four five six seven eight nine then eleven</p><p>twelve thirteen</p>"
custom_sanitize(html, :tag => "p")
#=> "one two three four five six seven eight nine then eleven twelve thirteen"
```

Example of multiple conditions:

```
custom_sanitize(html, {:tag => "p"}, {:tag => "div", :attributes => {:class => "title"})
```

=========

**For models [simple version]**

Including helper into helper file you just open it for ActionView environment. If you want to use this method within AR models, you should include it into ActiveRecord::Base before Rails has been loaded. But much easily just use CustomSanitizer class directly:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def no_html_content
    CustomSanitizer.new.do(content, :tag => "p")
  end

end

# Post.find(1).no_html_content
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I'm not familiar with this kind of code. In which file should this go and how to use it?

Comment: place the class code into `models/sanitizer.rb` and helper code into any helper file.

Comment: Oh thanks! But wait, is it overwriting Rails' default `sanitize`?

Comment: i've just improved the code for the cases when your html stuff has multiple nested tags like `<p>one</p><p><p><p>two</p></p></p>`. Previous code would insert 3 spaces before "two". Now its okay, only one space before.

Comment: thanks a lot! One last question, I put all the code above in `models/sanitizer.rb` then in `models/post.rb` I created a method and added this `custom_sanitize(self.content, :tags => %w("p"))` but I'm getting this undefined method `custom_sanitize' for #<Post:0xc296fc4>` I'm doing it wrong I think.

Comment: maybe `def custom_sanitize` has to be placed in the posts helper file or in `post.rb`?

Comment: I put it on `post.rb` (the part after # Helper) but I get an mass assignment error then I tried in `post_helper.rb` but I get the same undefined method error.

Comment: FYI, details about tag conditions: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/vendor/html-scanner/html/node.rb. As you see, you can use much more keys: parents, descendants, attributes etc...

Comment: Thanks again. But I get a `undefined method `do'` error. Please see my `edit`

Comment: Thats about name conflicts ) rename Sanitizer class to CustomSanitizer and sanitizer.rb to custom_sanitizer.rb